# Почему элемент стал не кликабельным?

Tags: javascript, html, css

В [проекте](http://www.bot.immo/realty/?type=advanced&section=sale)

почему-то стали не кликабельными эти ссылки

[image: скрин]

Есть подозрение что какие-то стили перебивают? Но что именно не известно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При нажатии на ссылку вы вызывает js функции через псевдо-протокол javascript, перепишите лучше так:

```
<a href="#" onclick="popWin('/realty/sol/569999/')">Berichten</a>
```

Comment: а как со вторым подпунктом и третьим? они другого характера

Comment: Аналогично первому, у меня работает.

Comment: да уже вижу, спасибо огромное.

Answer (score 2):

Это в любом случае плохая практика - примешивать JS-код к HTML-разметке, что через префикс `javascript:`, что через `onclick=`. Да еще и генерируется это всё внутри PHP, наверное.

Лучше писать чистый HTML

`<a href="#" class="berichten" data-sol="569999">Berichten</a>`

и чистый JS

```
$("a.berichten").on('click',function() {
    var link = '/realty/sol/'+ $(this).data('sol') + '/'
    //что там дальше с этим линком происходит
})
```

Да и PHP читабельнее станет, что-то типа 
`echo '<a href="#" data-sol="' + $id_num + '">Berichten</a>`

Comment: я делаю правки в этот проекте, поэтому что написано, то написано, но все равно спасибо за совет. И о да сайт не на php, а на pyton